# Decreasing Sigma Notation Sequence

Tags: notation

Sorry if this question may seem stupid (I am just fascinated with math), but is there anyway to have a decreasing sequence with sigma notation? Example: 160, 80, 40,...

Comment: $a_n = 5 \cdot 2^{5 - n}$?

Comment: What would be an example of an *increasing* sequence with sigma notation? (I don't really understand what you mean; hence this question.)

Comment: Or negative $A_n$'s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The usual use of capital sigma
($\sum$)
indicates a sum.
For example,
$\sum_{k=0}^4 \dfrac{160}{2^k}
$
means
$160+80+40+20+10$.

If you want to indicate
a *sequence* of values,
a common notation
(at least the one I use)
is
$(a_k)_{k=1}^n
$.

Here is the same example
as a sequence:

$\left(\dfrac{160}{2^k}\right)_{k=0}^4
$.
This means
$160, 80, 40, 20, 10
$.
Nothing is implied by the sequence; 
it is just a list of values in order.

There are a number
of similar notations.
One of the most common
is capital pi ($\prod$),
which indicates product.
For example,
$\prod_{k=0}^4\dfrac{160}{2^k}$.
means
$160 \times 80 \times 40 \times 20 \times 10
$.

Lower case sigma
($\sigma$)
has a variety of meanings.
It can be a variable, a permutation,
or the name of an algebra.
In number theory,
$\sigma(n)$
is the sum of the divisors
of $n$.

If you have any further questions,
I will be glad to try to answer them.

Comment: Thank you, I think I understand, is there any real world applications for sigma notation and capital pi? I watch this tv show called Numb3rs (They use real equations) and I see sigma and capital pi all the time.

Comment: There are incredible number of applications. Just look at questions here and some of the answers.

Comment: Can you write this: $n<=1*n, \quad n<=2*(n-1), ..., n<=n*1$; like this: $n <= (i(n-i+1))^n_{i=1}$?

Comment: Where would you use this?

Comment: I used it for proving an inequality. (But I wrote it down separately with $...$). My question still remains :)? If you know the answer.

Comment: Since this represents $n$ inequalities, I would write it $n \le i(n-1+1)$ for $i=1$ to $n$.