# Decreasing Summation Notation

Tags: discrete-mathematics, summation, notation

There is a previous question regarding a decreasing Sigma Notation Sequence ([Decreasing Sigma Notation Sequence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1726476/decreasing-sigma-notation-sequence)), however I feel this question is sufficiently different.
I am wondering why you could not write the summation of the sequence of {10, 9, 8, ..., 2, 1} as $\sum_{j=10-k+1}^{10} {j}$?

For example,

when k=1,
$\sum_{j=10-1+1}^{10} {j} = \sum_{j=10}^{10} {j} = 10$.

when k=2,
$\sum_{j=10-2+1}^{10} {j} = \sum_{j=9}^{10} {j} = 9+10$.

when k=3,
$\sum_{j=10-3+1}^{10} {j} = \sum_{j=8}^{10} {j} = 8+9+10$.

Comment: Sure, you can write this. (But the summation of {10, 9, 8, ..., 2, 1} is $\sum_{j=10-k+1}^{10} {j}$ only for $k = 10$.)

Comment: You can write whatever you want so long as it is well enough explained.  I will point out that you can write it out cleanly in a way that will confuse less people if you do it normally by just changing how you write the summands.  For instance you can write $10+9+8$ as $\sum\limits_{i=0}^2 (10-i)$

Comment: The concept is fine.  But conventional the notation of summation is $\sum\limits_{index;rules\ for\ indexing}^{final}$ so to explain what $k$ is I'd do $\sum\limits_{k=1;j=10-k+1}^{k=10} j$.  Although I'd probably find other options more to my taste such as $\sum_{k=1}^{10}(10 - k + 1)$ or $\sum_{k=10; -1}^1 k$.  And, of course $\sum_{k=0}^{9}(10-k)$ or many others.

Comment: Oh... wait.  You are assuming $k$ is a set value and not the index you were adding to and $j$ is the index.  Well in that case the actually set you are being asked to sum is when $k = 10$ so your sum would be $\sum_{j=10-10 + 1}^{10} j = \sum_{j=1}^{10}j$ which is just the normal notation.   And by the way if you are summing $\{m, m+1, ....., n\}$ it *IS* very common to use the notation $\sum_{j=m}^n j$.  The decreasing nature is easy to deal with (as addition is commutative) and you seem to be doing it in your head anyway.